# Map string values in Dataframe to integers using Python

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a Dataset which has a column containing name of colors(red, blue, green) and I want to convert these string values into int/float to fit into classifier. I was planning on using Python dictionary with keys as name of color and values as numbers.
This was my code:

```
color_dict = {'red':1, 'blue':2, 'green':3}
for i in train['column_name']:
     train['column_name'][i] = color_dict[i]
print(train['column_name'])
```

Sadly, this did not work.
What should I do differently to make it work?

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas, so I added the [tag:pandas] tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit] to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the question :)

```
train["column_name"] = train["column_name"].map(color_dict)
```

See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for map.

The reason your solution didn't work is a bit tricky. When you access a value like you did (using chained brackets), you're working on a copy of the DataFrame object. Instead, use `train.loc[i, "column_name"] = color_dict[i]` to set the a single value in a column. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) for more details.